# Real time div updating cause 500 Internal Server error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am looking to update div value in real time, it does the trick but whenmore users come load on server for mysql queries increase and 500 internal server error comes

My div is

```
<div id="bal"><?php echo $userbal; ?></div>
```

I have made a page userbal.php where i called this code

```
$check = $db->fetch("select * from users where username = ?", [$username]);
echo $userbal = $check->balance;
```

And added this code to main page to update div in real time

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(d){    
loadstation(d);
});

function loadstation(d){
$("#bal").load("userbal.php");
setTimeout(loadstation, 5000);
}
</script>
```

It works the purpose of div updating in real time But issue is it is causing too much load on server and server is getting 500 internal server error so is there a smart way to update div in real time without calling that page again and again by all users or how to optimize queries to control extensive server usage

Comment: better go with a websocket implementation or server-send events

Comment: I am new to wesockets,can yo guide howto write it in my case given above

Comment: there are plenty of examples on this site and others

Comment: ajax long-polling might be an alternative: https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery